# Android DatePickerDialog Cancel button not working

Tags: android

I am using `DatePicker Dialog`. 
When a button clicked datepicker show
everything is ok.

But my `BUTTON_NEGATIVE` button not working. I clicked `NEGATIVE_BUTTON`, diloagpicker close but date set.

This is my CalendarItem.java file:

```
    public class CalendarItem extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        private Button pregnant_button;
        private Button numbered_button;

        public CalendarItem(Button pregnant_button) {
            this.pregnant_button = pregnant_button;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            /*
            tarih önceden ayarlanmışsa,
             */
            long get_miliseconds_to_date    = MotherActivity.preferences.getLong(MotherActivity.USER_DUE_DATE_MS,0);
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if(get_miliseconds_to_date != 0 ) {
                c.setTimeInMillis(get_miliseconds_to_date);
            }
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

            dialog.setButton(
                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
dialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("Button_value","" + which + " ---- " + " negatif");
                    }
                }
            });

            dialog.setButton(
                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Set",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.d("Button_value","" + which + " ---- " + " Pozitif");
                        }
                    }
            );

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            pregnant_button.setText(dayOfMonth + " " + MotherActivity.turkish_monts[monthOfYear] + " " + year);
            long miliseconds_date       = date_to_miliseconds(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = MotherActivity.preferences.edit();
            editor.putLong(MotherActivity.USER_DUE_DATE_MS, miliseconds_date);
            editor.apply();
        }

        private long date_to_miliseconds(int year, int month, int day){
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(year,month,day,00,00);
            return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }
    }
```

Help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried getActivity().getDialog().dismiss() or getParent().getActivity().getDialog().dismiss() ?

Comment: I try now and I get "Cannot resolve method 'getDialog()'" error

Comment: Have a look on http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: Try to override onDismiss method in your DialogFragment

Comment: Yes Itry this but not working. I cant understand :(

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem easily.

Only I added one line code than is a boolean variable.

```
  private Button pregnant_button;
        //add this line default = false
        private boolean printer     = false;

        public CalendarItem(Button pregnant_button) {
            this.pregnant_button = pregnant_button;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            /*
            tarih önceden ayarlanmışsa,
             */
            long get_miliseconds_to_date    = MotherActivity.preferences.getLong(MotherActivity.USER_DUE_DATE_MS,0);
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if(get_miliseconds_to_date != 0 ) {
                c.setTimeInMillis(get_miliseconds_to_date);
            }
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);


            dialog.setButton(
                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "İptal",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setButton(
                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Tamam",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                                printer = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            if( printer ) {
                pregnant_button.setText(dayOfMonth + " " + MotherActivity.turkish_monts[monthOfYear] + " " + year);
                long miliseconds_date       = date_to_miliseconds(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = MotherActivity.preferences.edit();
                editor.putLong(MotherActivity.USER_DUE_DATE_MS, miliseconds_date);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
```